# A topological category which is a subcategory of Set

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory

In category theory it is possible to freely chose what are objects and what are morphisms as long as the definitions fulfills the axioms for a category.

Now, I'm trying to construct a natural category of topological spaces, equivalent with **Top**, but being a subcategory of **Set** (which **Top** isn't). My approach is letting the objects be the [Kuratowski closure operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms), usually denoted $\text{cl}$.

I have some problems with the morphisms and the approach however (see [Does this category explain continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853785/does-this-category-explain-continuity)).

My question is simply:

> would a function $\hat f:\text{cl}\to\text{cl}'$ defined by  $\hat f(S,T)=(f(S),f(T))$ make sense for continuous functions $f:X\to X'$?

Are there more to check except that $\text{Im}\hat f\subseteq \text{cl}'$, for these functions to be adequate morphisms?

It's understand that $(S,T)\in \text{cl}\subseteq \mathcal P(X)\times \mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $cl\in \mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(X)$? I guess you mean that you consider a function $f:A\to B$ as a subset $f\subset A\times B$ s.t. for all $a\in A: \exists! b\in B s.t. (a,b)\in f$?

Comment: @user2520938, I wrote $\text{cl}\subseteq \mathcal P(X)\times \mathcal P(X)$. The operator cl is a relation $\subseteq \mathcal P(X)\times \mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: But then you might as well write $(S,\overline{S})$. Then it is also clear that $\hat f(S,\bar{S})=(f(S),f(\bar{S}))$ is not well defined, since it need not be an element of $cl'$. $(f(S),f(\bar{S}))\in cl'$ iff $\overline{f(S)}=f(\overline{S})$. This is true for all $S\subset X$ iff $f$ is a homeomorphism (see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_iff_Image_of_Closure_equals_Closure_of_Image)

Comment: also, $cl$ is not just a relation, its a function, which is a specific class of relations.

Comment: @user2520938 Please write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you consider $cl\subset \mathcal{P}(X)\times\mathcal{P}(X)$, you cannot plug any pair $(S,T)$ into $\hat f:cl\to cl'$, but only those $(S,T)\in cl$, and these are exactly the pairs $(S,\overline{S})$. Hence the map
$$\hat f:cl\to cl':(S,\overline{S})\mapsto (f(S),f(\bar{S}))$$
is well defined iff $(f(S),f(\bar{S}))\in cl'$ for all $S\in X$. I.e. $(f(S),f(\overline{S}))=(f(S),\overline{f(S)})$, i.e. $f(\overline{S})=\overline{f(S)}$ for all $S\subset X$. And this is not true for general continuous $f$.

---

I didn't check it, but I think you'll want to consider a contravariant functor, since generally pre-images are better behaved wrt the topology then images.